# LNK2019 using QQuickWidget

Tags: qt5

[image]

Quite a strange error just as the image above.

I just drag a QQuickWidget in then I got this Link error.Everything went well again after I delete that QQuickWidget.

A QT protosomatic class will be included automatically isn't it? Or I have to do something like add a dll dependency like what must be done when using VS? If so then how to do so in QT5?

Or maybe it's caused by some missing dlls?

Thanks for answering.



ps: I'm using QT5.5.0

Comment: Did you clean your build directory? Delete it, run qmake and try again.

Comment: Well almost forget this question.I figure it out myself that I need to rerun qmake, the same as what you said here, thanks anyway.